# How to close jQuery accordion before opening next one?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, accordion

After opening an accordion item and then clicking on a new accordion item, I want it to first close the open one and then open the new one.

Here's my current code:

```
jQuery('.acclink').click(function () {
    jQuery("#accordion").accordion("activate", -1); // this closes anything open
    jQuery(jQuery(this).attr('href')).click(); // this is supposed to open the new one but doesn't. It WILL work when the above function is commented out.
    return false;
});
```

Here's my page: http://www.savedeth.com/objectivescenes/
What am I missing?

Comment: Doesn't the accordion do this by default?

Comment: not exactly. It will slide the new one in from above or below. I want it to entirely close, then open a new one.

Comment: Does this just have to do with the speed of the animation perhaps?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No need to type jQuery, `$('#accordion').<method>` is enough.

Are you sure that `jQuery(jQuery(this).attr('href'))` is selecting what you want? 
Print it using `console.log(Query(jQuery(this).attr('href')))`

I think accordion already does everything you need by itself.

Probably `$('#accordion').accordion()` is the simplest solution.

Comment: Here's the sample page: http://www.savedeth.com/objectivescenes/ (click on the "section" links)

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
$(document).ready(function() { ("#accordion").accordion;});
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use jqueryui's, [accordion](http://jqueryui.com/demos/accordion/) which does this by default.

Comment: ... not exactly. Check my example page. It should close the accordion, fully, then open again.